# Creating sub-groups in Xcode for FILE Template

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-template

I am trying to create a custom FILE template (not Project Template). where i need to create the file in a new group (new folder) which should also be created along with the File. i have searched the net but there is no reference for File Template But is available for Project Template. Is what i am trying possible? direct me where i can accomplish this.

Thanks in Advance

```
The structure should be like this
-Folder[already available]   
--- New folder [Created in the file template name]  
------- A.h  [by file template]  
------- A.m  [by file template]
```